# How can i send and recieve using sockets at the same time on the same port

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am trying to do chat application and I'm using tcp sockets and threading the question is how can I wait for command and send command at the same time on the same socket

```
public void GetTextFather()
    {
        string Command = "";
        string text = "";
        while (Command == "")
            Command = Functions.serverrecievetext(ip, port);

        if (Command == "Text")
        {
            while (text == "")
                text = Functions.serverrecievetext(ip, port);
            if (text != "")
            {

                listBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { this.listBox1.Items.Add(name + ":" + text); });
                Thread t = new Thread(GetTextFather);
                t.Start();
            }

        }
        if (Command == "Typing")
        {
            label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { label1.Visible = true; });
            Thread t = new Thread(GetTextFather);
            t.Start();
        }
        if (Command == "NotTyping")
        {
            label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate { label1.Visible = false; });
            Thread t = new Thread(GetTextFather);
            t.Start();
        }

    }
```

the send button click

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {string text=textBox1.Text;
    listBox1.Items.Add("You:" + text);
    if (text.Length != 0)
    {
        if (!flag)
        {Functions.ClientSendTextPortsixty("Text", port);
            Functions.ClientSendTextPortsixty(text, port);

        }
        else
        {Functions.ServerSendbyip("Text", ip, port);
             Functions.ServerSendbyip(text, ip, port);

        }
    }
    textBox1.Text = "";
    }
```

function send is simple and sends a text through socket and the receive gets a text. 
I have GetTextSon() same as GetTextFather 
if you need any more info just comment below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I am not understanding the problem correctly, but this code has worked for me in the past. I'm going to ignore the UI piece, and just write the socket code (this is from memory, but should be pretty close):

```
public class ChatClient
{
   public event Action<String> MessageRecieved;

   private TcpClient socket;
   public ChatClient(String host, int port)
   {
       socket = new TcpClient(host, port);
       Thread listenThread = new Thread(ReadThread);
       listenThread.Start();
   }

   private void ReadThread()
   {
       NetworkStream netStream = socket.GetStream ();
       while (socket.Connected)
       {
           //Read however you want, something like:
           // Reads NetworkStream into a byte buffer. 
            byte[] bytes = new byte[socket.ReceiveBufferSize];

            // Read can return anything from 0 to numBytesToRead.  
            // This method blocks until at least one byte is read.
            netStream.Read (bytes, 0, (int)socket.ReceiveBufferSize);

            // Returns the data received from the host to the console. 
            MessageRecieved(Encoding.UTF8.GetString (bytes));
       }
   }

   public void SendMessage(string msg)
   {
      NetworkStream netStream = socket.GetStream ();
      Byte[] sendBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (msg);
      netStream.Write (sendBytes, 0, sendBytes.Length);
   }
}
```

Now, to solve the problem of differentiation, I split all my messages into two parts, the "Command" and the "Data". For example, if you want to send a "Kick User" command:

```
Send: "KickUser:bob"
Recieve: "UserKicked:bob"
```

A chat message from another user would be something like:

```
Recieve: "ChatMessage:Hi"
```

And whoever uses the client just listens on the MessageRecieved event and parses the messages appropriately, raising whatever events are necessary for the UI to update.

Let me know what you think!